# Hover effect for SwiftUI Shapes for the mac

Tags: swiftui

I'd like to create a hover effect for SwiftUI shapes for the mac which takes the actual shape into account.
The `onHover` modifier is not good because it fires when the mouse enters the frame, rather than the SwiftUI `Shape`. `hoverEffect` is not available for the Mac.

How to create a hover effect that takes the underlying shape into account?

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct HoverViewModifier : ViewModifier {
    @State private var hovered = false
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .foregroundColor(hovered ? .accentColor : .primary)
            .onHover { isHovered in
                self.hovered = isHovered
            }
    }
}

struct MyStar : Shape {
    func path(in rect : CGRect) -> Path {
        let points = [
            (50, 0), (61, 33), (97, 34), (69, 56), (79, 90), (50, 70), (20, 90), (30, 56), ( 2, 34), (38, 33)
        ].map { (x : CGFloat, y : CGFloat) in
            CGPoint(x: x * rect.width / 100, y: y * rect.height / 100)
        }
        var path = Path()
        path.addLines(points)
        return path
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Circle().modifier(HoverViewModifier())
            MyStar().modifier(HoverViewModifier())
        }.frame(width: 200, height: 100)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried chainig `onHover` to the shapes and not their containers?

Comment: yes, same results.

Comment: @Tamas Unfortunately, I think you may have to make a custom solution by manually getting positions of mouse and the views, then checking if the mouse position point is within a path. You would use something like [`contains(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624345-contains) to know if the point is with that. You can reuse this `UIBezierPath` too because it can also be used to generate the path in your `path(in:)` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this excellent article https://swiftui-lab.com/a-powerful-combo/ which demonstrates how to track mouse movement.

For this purpose, the author uses `NSViewRepresentable` and `NSHostingView` to get access to AppKit's `NSView`.

Instead of returning the mouse positions, we could return a boolean value indicating whether the mouse is inside the `path` of the `Shape`.

Since our content is a `Shape` and not a `View`, the where clauses need to be adjusted accordingly: `where Content : Shape`.

The solution uses `NSTrackingArea` with the `.mouseMoved` option. It makes sense to add the `.mouseEnteredAndExited` option in addition to ensure that the non-hovered state is restored when the mouse leaves the view.

To connect a `Shape` to the `TrackingAreaView` on the one hand and to the `HoverViewModifier` on the other hand, extensions to `Shape` can be created. Also the `@State` in the `HooverViewModifier` must be replaced by an `@ObservedObject` to be able to access it from the Shape. A corresponding `ObservableObject` can simply look like this:

```
class HoverModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var hovered: Bool = false
}
```

The extension could look like this:

```
extension Shape {
    func hover(modifier: HoverViewModifier) -> some View {
        return self.mouse { inside in
            modifier.hoverModel.hovered = inside
        }
        .modifier(modifier)
    }
    
    func mouse(insideShape: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) -> some View {
        TrackingAreaView(insideShape: insideShape) { self }
    }
}
```

Accordingly, the calls must be changed slightly:

```
Circle().hover(modifier: HoverViewModifier())
MyStar().hover(modifier: HoverViewModifier())
```

A complete example with the adapted code from the question combined with the slightly extended example from the article mentioned at the beginning could then look something like this:

```
import SwiftUI

class HoverModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var hovered: Bool = false
}

struct HoverViewModifier : ViewModifier {
    @ObservedObject var hoverModel = HoverModel()
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .foregroundColor(hoverModel.hovered ? .accentColor : .primary)
    }
}

extension Shape {
    func hover(modifier: HoverViewModifier) -> some View {
        return self.mouse { inside in
            modifier.hoverModel.hovered = inside
        }
        .modifier(modifier)
    }
    
    func mouse(insideShape: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) -> some View {
        TrackingAreaView(insideShape: insideShape) { self }
    }
}

struct MyStar : Shape {
    func path(in rect : CGRect) -> Path {
        let points = [
            (50, 0), (61, 33), (97, 34), (69, 56), (79, 90), (50, 70), (20, 90), (30, 56), ( 2, 34), (38, 33)
        ].map { (x : CGFloat, y : CGFloat) in
            CGPoint(x: x * rect.width / 100, y: y * rect.height / 100)
        }
        var path = Path()
        path.addLines(points)
        return path
    }
    
}

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Circle().hover(modifier: HoverViewModifier())
            MyStar().hover(modifier: HoverViewModifier())
        }.frame(width: 200, height: 100)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct TrackingAreaView<Content>: View where Content : Shape {
    let insideShape: (Bool) -> Void
    let content: () -> Content
    
    init(insideShape: @escaping (Bool) -> Void, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.insideShape = insideShape
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TrackingAreaRepresentable(insideShape: insideShape, content: self.content())
    }
}

struct TrackingAreaRepresentable<Content>: NSViewRepresentable where Content: Shape {
    let insideShape: (Bool) -> Void
    let content: Content
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSHostingView<Content> {
        return TrackingNSHostingView(insideShape: insideShape, rootView: self.content)
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSHostingView<Content>, context: Context) {
    }
}

class TrackingNSHostingView<Content>: NSHostingView<Content> where Content : Shape {
    let insideShape: (Bool) -> Void
    var path = Path()
    
    init(insideShape: @escaping (Bool) -> Void, rootView: Content) {
        self.insideShape = insideShape
        super.init(rootView: rootView)
        setupTrackingArea()
    }
    
    override func layout() {
        super.layout()
        self.path = rootView.path(in: self.bounds)
    }
    
    required init(rootView: Content) {
        fatalError("init(rootView:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupTrackingArea() {
        let options: NSTrackingArea.Options = [.mouseMoved, .mouseEnteredAndExited, .activeAlways, .inVisibleRect]
        self.addTrackingArea(NSTrackingArea(rect: .zero, options: options, owner: self, userInfo: nil))
    }
        
    override func mouseExited(with event: NSEvent) {
        self.insideShape(false)
    }
    
    override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
        return self.checkInside(with: event)
    }
    
    override func mouseEntered(with event: NSEvent) {
        return self.checkInside(with: event)
    }
    
    private func checkInside(with event: NSEvent) {
        let inside = path.contains(self.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil))
        self.insideShape(inside)
    }
}
```

**Demo**

[image: hover demo]

Comment: Thanks! Pretty awesome! I was able to get rid of `ObservableObject` which further improves your answer. See it below.

Comment: Yes, the private "@State" is nicer.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get rid of the `ObservableObject` from @stephan-schlecht's answer and make an `onHoverInside` modifier similar to the built-in `onHover` like this:

```swift
extension Shape {
    func onHoverInside(action: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) -> some View {
        TrackingAreaView(insideShape: action) { self }
    }
}

struct MyHoveredShape<Content> : View where Content : Shape {
    @State private var hovered : Bool = false
    let shape : Content
    
    var body: some View {
        shape
            .onHoverInside { isHoveredInside in
                hovered = isHoveredInside
            }
            .foregroundColor(hovered ? .accentColor : .primary)
    }
}

extension Shape {
    func myHoverModifier() -> some View {
        return MyHoveredShape(shape: self)
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Circle().myHoverModifier()
            MyStar().myHoverModifier()
        }.frame(width: 200, height: 100)
    }
}
```

The rest goes according to his answer.